# Using frame by frame animation with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

Is there any good way to use frame by frame animation `AnimationDrawable` using UIL library. AnimationDrawable accept only `BitmpaDrawable` . Is there any way to convert quickly to bitmaps my images or any maybe there is method like imageLoader.getBitmap, I haven't find anything like that.

Please help , I would be very grateful for any help .
 **Edit** I have my images in assets folder. Maybe there any way to get bitmap from cache or something else . I need open new activity , maybe several times . I need to show animation from files , but if I use decode it takes a lot of time to decode them . Please suggest something

Comment: You can use methods `ImageLoader.loadImage(...)` and get Bitmap in listener. Or you can use `ImageLoader.loadImageSync(...)` which returns Bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are resources you can use this for obtain Bitmap:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                           R.drawable.icon_resource);
```

else, if you want donwload the image you can use this:

```
String name = c.getString(url);
URL urlAux = new URL(name);
ImageView prueba = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.iv_prueba);
if (prueba != null) {
    Bitmap bitmap =
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(urlAux.openConnection().getInputStream());
    prueba.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have my images in assets folder. Maybe there any way to get bitmap from cache or something else . I need open new activity , maybe several times . I need to show animation from files , but if I use decode it takes a lot of time to decode them . Please suggest something